# How can I create a non-nullable variable when it's initialized in an event?

Tags: c#, non-nullable

This is razor code but I think the same can happen in most any C# code in an event driven architecture.

```
private List<User> Users { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Users = await Context.Users.Include(u => u.Address).ToListAsync();
}
```

So the above code will initialize Users before it is ever accessed. However, it puts up a warning that a non-nullable variable is not being initialized.

Is this a case of assigning "default!" to it which is my way of saying don't worry it'll be initialized before it is accessed?

**Update:** This occurs inside a .razor page in the @code part. So it exists while the html is being rendered to pass back to the user's browser. I'm writing this code in an ASP.NET Core Blazor app.

The problem here is the Users object needs to be accessible to all the code in the .razor file. But the code is loaded in the async method. And this method is called as part of the .razor file creation, so it needs to be in there.

Comment: _"event driven architecture"_ - uhhhh... I think you're misusing that term. You know how _class invariants_ work, right?

Comment: _"Is this a case of assigning "default!" to it which is my way of saying don't worry it'll be initialized before it is accessed?"_ - doing that is just bad class design. Initialization should happen inside the constructor because the constructor exists to enforce class invariants (I know ctors can't be `async`: so if you have async logic or any IO then that should be done by a factory function which _then_ calls the ctor after it has the data that the ctor needs)....

Comment: ...wich makes me wonder what your `private List<User> Users` property is for if it's ephemeral - is this for a WinForms or other UI component? If so, then `Users` should be an `ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> { get; } = new();` and _not_ `List<User> { get; set; }` (being `get`-only ensures its reference will never be replaced; to populate it you would clear-and-add the `ObservableCollection` with `UserViewModel` (which would wrap `User` with a WPF/etc-friendly interface)...

Comment: Ah, you're using Blazor?

Comment: @Dai yes. And I'm new to it - my previous experience, about 5 years ago, was ASP.NET MVC. So new to Blazor and new to non-nullable in C# (I was a CEO the last 7 years and so no programming all that time).

Comment: In Blazor, the same concepts as WPF apply: your `Users` property should be a `get`-only `ObservableCollection` which is cleared-and-repopulated by your `OnInitializedAsync` method - though presumably you'd want to reload the list at a point in future?

Comment: @Dai you've given me some very good guidance on how to approach this. thank you. Also, if you want to put all that as the answer, I'm happy to accept it to give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comments, with too much pontification:

- In OOP, regardless of language (be it Java, C#, C++, Swift, etc), the *purpose* of a `class`'s constructor is to initialize the object-instance's state from any parameters, *and also* to establish [*class invariants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant).

  - (Btw, don't equate or confuse *invariant* with *immutability*: immutability is just a particular kind of invariant, it's perfectly acceptable for a class' objects to be mutable)
- The principle of class-invariants is more-often-than-lot (in my opinion) lost on so-many (perhaps even most?) users of C#, specifically, because of how the C# language (and its associated documentation and libraries) has evolved towards preferring default (parameterless) constructors, *post-construction* initialization, and mutable properties - all of which cannot be reconciled with the *CS-theoretical*, not practical, limits of static analysis which the C# compiler uses for `#nullable` warnings.

  - The simple fact is *only* a `class`'s constructor can make guarantees about the state of any of its instance fields (including auto-properties) - whereas (excepting `required` members in C# 11), a C# object-initializer is evaluated post-construction, is entirely optional, sets entirely arbitrary and non-exhaustive members.
- Therefore, to make use of `#nullable` to the full-extent, one must simply *get used* to getting into the habit of writing parameterized constructors, despite their "*expressive redundancy*" in most cases (e.g. in [a POCO DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object)) having to repeat the class's members as ctor parameters and then assign each property in the ctor.

  - <sub>Though at least `record` types in C# 9 simplify this - but `record` types aren't as immutable as they seem: properties can still be overwritten with invalid values *after* the ctor has run in an object-initializer, which breaks the concept of class-invariants being enforced by the constructor - I'm really not happy with how that turned out in C# 9, grrr.</sub>
- I appreciate that this isn't possible in many cases, such as with Entity Framework and EF Core, which (as of early 2023) still doesn't support binding database query results to constructor parameters, only to property-setters - but people often are unaware that many other libraries/frameworks *do* support ctor binding, such as Newtonsoft.Json supports deserializing JSON objects to immutable C# objects via `[JsonConstructor]` and attaching `[JsonProperty]` to each ctor parameter, for example.
- In other cases, namely UI/UX code, where your visual component/control/widget must inherit from some framework-provided base-class (e.g. WinForms' `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, or WPF's `Visual` or `Control`, or in Blazor: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase`) - you'll find yourself with seemingly contradictory precepts: you can only "initialize" the Control's state /data in the `OnLoad`/`OnInitializedAsync` method (not the constructor), but the C# compiler's `#nullable` analysis recognizes that only the constructor can initialize class members and properly establish that certain fields will never be `null` at any point. It's a conundrum and the documentation and official examples and tutorials *do* often gloss this over (sometimes even with `= null!`, [which I feel is *just wrong*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74496499/159145)).
- Taking Blazor's `ComponentBase` for example (as this is what the OP's code is targeting, after-all): [immediately after when the `ComponentBase` subclass is created (i.e. the ctor runs), the `SetParametersAsync` method is called, only after that *then* is `OnInitializedAsync` called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0) - and `OnInitializedAsync` can fail or need to be `await`ed, which means that the "laws" about constructors definitely still apply: any code consuming a `ComponentBase` type cannot necessarily depend any late initialization by `OnInitializedAsync` to be guaranteed, *especially* not any error-handling code.

  - For example, if the ctor left the `List<User> Users { get; }` property uninitialized (and therefore `null`, despite the type not being `List<User>?`) and `OnInitializedAsync` (which would set it to a non-`null` value) were to fail, and then if that `ComponentBase` subclass object were to be passed to some custom-error handling logic, then that error-handler itself would fail if it (*rightfully*, but incorrectly) assumed that the `Users` property would never be `null`.

    - However this convoluted arrangement could have been avoided if Microsoft designed Blazor to support some kind of *`Component`-factory* system whereby the `OnInitialized{Async}` logic *could* be moved into a factory-method or ctor with that all-or-nothing guarantee that we need for software we can reason about. But anyway...
- So given the above, there exist a few solutions:

  - If this were a system entirely under your control <sub>(which Blazor is not, so this advice doesn't apply to you)</sub> then I would recommend you redesign the system to use factory-methods instead of post-ctor object initialization.
  - But as this is Blazor, it shares certain similarities in its databinding approach with WPF, "XAML", WinForms and others: namely its roots in having *long-lived mutable view-models* implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

    - And this is the most important factor: because the *view-model concept* means that you shouldn't have `List<T>` as the collection-type for a property that will be used for data-binding: you're meant to use [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0), which solves the problem: `ObservableCollection<T>` is meant to be initialized *only once* by the constructor (thus satisfying the never-`null` problem), and *is designed to be long-lived and mutable*, so it's perfectly-fine to populate it in `OnInitializedAsync` and `OnParametersSet{Async}`, which is how Blazor operates.

**Therefore**, in my opinion, you should change your code to this:

```cs
class UsersListComponent : ComponentBase
{

    private Boolean isBusy;

    public Boolean IsBusy
    {
        get { return this.isBusy; }
        private set { if( this.isBusy != value ) { this.isBusy = value; this.RaiseOnNotifyPropertyChanged( nameof(this.IsBusy); } // INPC boilerplate, ugh: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65813816/c-sharp-blazor-server-display-live-data-using-inotifypropertychanged
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await this.ReloadUsersAsync(); // Also call `ReloadUsersAsync` in `OnParametersSetAsync` as-appropriate based on your application.
    }

    private async Task ReloadUsersAsync()
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
        this.Users.Clear(); // <-- The ObservableCollection will raise its own collection-modified events for you, which will be handled by the UI components data-bound to the exposed Users collection.

        try
        {
            List<User> users = await this.Context.Users
                .Include(u => u.Address)
                .ToListAsync();

            // ObservableCollection<T> doesn't support AddRange for historical reasons that we're now stuck with, ugh: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18087#issuecomment-359197102

            foreach( User u in users ) this.Users.Add( u );
        }
        finally
        {
            this.IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how, if the data-loading in `OnInitializeAsync`, via `ReloadUsersAsync`, fails due to an exception being thrown from Entity Framework (which is common, e.g. SQL Server timeout, database down, etc) then the class-invariants of `UsersListComponent` (i.e. that the `Users` collection is never `null` and the property always exposes a single long-lived object-reference) always remain true, which means any code can safely consume your `UsersListComponent` without risk of a dreaded unexpected `NullReferenceException`.

(And the `IsBusy` part is just because it's an inevitable thing to add to any ViewModel/XAML-databound class that performs some IO).

Comment: This is super helpful. The explanation behind it especially so.

Comment: The practice of assigning null ! as the solution to this issue in Blazor is officially endorsed by the Blazor project (see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47736, answer posted by GitHub user javiercn). (I think "null !" is better than "default !" because it's more explicit about what is happening.)

Comment: @Hammerite I'm aware - there's also _criminal_ use of `= null!` in EF Core's documentation too. I feel that MS is advocating that out of pragmatic desire to address all the people more concerned with compiler-warnings they might not fully understand - and it takes far less effort to tell people to suppress warnings than it does to educate them in CS/OOP concepts when the same audience often lacks any formal CS education. Even so, that doesn't make it "right" when _demonstrably correct_ approaches exist (even when they do require a lot more fore-thought and understanding).

Comment: There are cases in which no "demonstrably correct" alternative exists. Your example code in this answer works only because there is a sensible non-null default value for a member of type ObservableCollection<T>, namely an empty one. It is not uncommon to have a member of class type that has no such sensible default state, perhaps because it is heavyweight and must be constructed using the component's parameters, thus can only be constructed in OnInitialised[Async]() and not in the constructor. Your advice to categorically avoid assigning null ! is not practical in the circumstances.

Comment: @Hammerite "not practical" is entirely subjective - we're entitled to our own opinions :)